# PayPal SetExpressCheckout stops working after CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile

Tags: node.js, express, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to implement recurring payments with the Express Checkout NVP API. After a successful flow SetExpressCheckout -> redirect to PayPal and acception -> GetExpressCheckoutDetails -> CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, when I try to obtain a new token by calling SetExpressCheckout (let's say when I try to repeat the flow for another user), I get an error:

```
{ TIMESTAMP: '2014-05-14T09:09:17Z',
  CORRELATIONID: '9072df3650d68',
  ACK: 'Failure',
  VERSION: '113',
  BUILD: '10958405',
  L_ERRORCODE0: '10413',
  L_SHORTMESSAGE0: 'Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.',
  L_LONGMESSAGE0: 'The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.',
  L_SEVERITYCODE0: 'Error' }
```

If I delete `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: 0` from the request, I get another error, but this one with a token (which is the same on each request):

```
{ TOKEN: 'EC-2U787650918701539',
  TIMESTAMP: '2014-05-14T09:13:09Z',
  CORRELATIONID: 'd3f276219cab9',
  ACK: 'Failure',
  VERSION: '113',
  BUILD: '10958405',
  L_ERRORCODE0: '10410',
  L_SHORTMESSAGE0: 'Invalid token',
  L_LONGMESSAGE0: 'Invalid token.',
  L_SEVERITYCODE0: 'Error' }
```

So PayPal gives me a token, but says it's invalid. I guess it's not a problem with arguments or their values, but with tokens. For some reason PayPal just stops to emit new tokens in response to SetExpressCheckout requests after the first successful flow.

The complete flow:

1) SetExpressCheckout

```
USR: [...],
PWD: [...],
SIGNATURE: [...],
VERSION: 113,
METHOD: 'SetExpressCheckout',
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: 0,
MAXAMT: 5.0,
L_BILLINGTYPE0: 'RecurringPayments',
L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0: [...],
REQCONFIRMSHIPPING: 0,
NOSHIPPING: 1,
BRANDNAME: [...],
EMAIL: [...],
LANDINGPAGE: 'Login',
cancelUrl: [...],
returnUrl: [...]
```

2) Redirect to `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=TOKEN` where a user accepts the billing agreement.

3) GetExpressCheckoutDetails (credentials, METHOD and TOKEN from the step 1).

4) CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile

```
USR: [...],
PWD: [...],
SIGNATURE: [...],
VERSION: 113,
METHOD: 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile',
TOKEN: [from the step 1],
PAYERID: [from the step 3],
PROFILESTARTDATE: [ISO date string],
DESC: [...],
BILLINGPERIOD: 'Month',
BILLINGFREQUENCY: 1,
AMT: 5.0,
AUTOBILLOUTAMT: 'AddToNextBilling',
CURRENCYCODE: 'USD',
MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS: 1,
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0: 'Digital',
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0: [...],
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0: 5.0,
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0: 1
```

That's it. I use node.js [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to accomplish the requests.

Comment: I am unable to recreate this error using the same parameters. Can you post your calls to both SetExpressCheckout and CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by sending GET requests instead of POST. [Here](https://gist.github.com/nDmitry/10f8e967869d477bc8aa) are the final fields set and a function I use to send GET requests to PayPal API.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely sure the request you provided for the second time around is correct?  It seems like there must be something happening that you're unaware of, or some data must be getting included in that request that we're not seeing here..??  Maybe your log is saving from the original request (via a session or something) but the second one that's failing is actually a new request with additional parameters that is getting sent to PayPal but not what's getting saved in your log..??

When I [replicate your request on my test server](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/temp/SetExpressCheckout.php) it works as expected no matter how many times I repeat it.

The error you're getting about cart totals only shows up when the following is NOT true.

AMT = ITEMAMT + SHIPPINGAMT + HANDLINGAMT + TAXAMT

When I add items to the same request, but purposefully make the prices not add up, then I get the error you're showing that you're getting on the second time through.  You can [see that here](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/temp/SetExpressCheckout-error.php).

So the curious thing is that the request you're showing for that second time around doesn't have any item or amount info at all other than a MAXAMT just like the first one had.  You are sending an amount of 0.00, though, which means if shipping, handling, tax, or any item were added with a price you would end up with the error you're getting.

Are you sure one of those parameters aren't somehow getting included in the request that your log isn't catching somehow..??  Is that a raw dump of exactly what gets passed into your HTTP request?

The fact of the matter is there has to be something that PayPal's server is seeing that would cause it to trigger this error, and I've never once seen that error when it wasn't a simple miscalculation of those values.

If you can't track anything like that down you'll need to submit this to [PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts).  I wouldn't even bother explaining all of this info about going around a second time, though.  Simply provide the raw API request and response that failed to them, and question the fact that you're getting such an error when you're not even including any amount or item details in your request.

Comment: They're included. As I said, the first time the flow is successful, it wouldn't be without them.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that the first time somehow.  What it sounds like to me is you're passing data around in session variables or something like that and they're not getting cleared out or reset the way you think they should be.  Need to see full samples of the working API requests as well as the follow up that fails.  Also, I'm a little confused by the very first error stating your cart totals aren't matching.  That again seems like maybe session data is getting left over and item totals aren't adding up to the grand total.  Full request samples would help a lot.

Comment: I added all requests to the question. Yes, I think it's something related to sessions, because when I try to repeat the flow, PayPal skips the login page and I find myself on the agreement page as a logged in user (in spite of the token from SEC is invalid). But I don't know where the state can be stored on my side, so I guess it's PayPal doesn't clear the session somehow.

Comment: Though the problem can be solved after server restart, so maybe node.js keeps some session data.

Comment: I don't see anything new as far as requests in the question..??  I don't want to see things like "from step 1" I want to see the actual raw requests.  For example, I'm trying to see if the same token from the first (working) transaction ends up getting sent with the second set of requests or not, among other things.  If you can provide full samples just like the sample set I provided that would help a lot.

Comment: If I omit the `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT` field, the token from previous transaction is shown (as part of the ‘Invalid token’ error). If not, I get this weird ‘The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts’ error without a token (both errors are in the question).

Comment: I tried to complete the second transaction from different clients, clean cookies, different requests fields sets, different emails for SEC EMAIL field and so on, hence it's not a client-side problem. It can't be on PayPal's side either, because all I have to do to solve the problem is restart my node.js server. But I tried to use both request library and node.js bundled API only (thought maybe request lib caches something) and got the same results, so I just don't know where a problem is.

Comment: The cart totals problem is pretty easy to fix.  It means exactly what it says.  If you'd post a sample of the requests I could help you.  Not sure why you're not doing that..??

Comment: I posted requests fields that I use (as POSTs with NVP bodies) and their values that matters. ‘From the step 1’ means I get a field value from a response dynamically. Why do you want to see some strings like description or brand name? The problem isn't there if it works once.

Comment: What Andrew is saying is if we have the exact code you are using we can test it, exactly as you have it. There may be something different about the way node.js is creating the request or the way you are storing data etc.

Comment: Also, I have tested the calls with the same exact parameters besides the `[...]` strings which I replaced with gibberish. It doesn't appear to be a problem with the parameters you are sending.

Comment: Seeing the actual requests will often present an obvious problem that you just didn't realize was happening.  Saying "same as before" or anything like that is an assumption.  Without seeing that actual value there, there's no way to know for sure that it actually got filled out the way you expected.  You're sure making it hard for people to help you.

Comment: I'd really like to see the full, original request for when you got the cart totals error.  That seems to be the root of your problem, right?  It's a very simple thing to solve, and if you'd post the full request you'd probably see the problem yourself.

Comment: Ok, [here](https://gist.github.com/nDmitry/a35233800fe3ef9cd6c9) are  my middlewares, don't really know what you're expecting to see there, just standard Express app)

Comment: BTW, I tried to decrement Merchant API version to 57 and got ‘Invalid token’ error instead of ‘The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.’ without removing `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT`. One more interesting thing—if I add to SEC `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_[NAME|AMT|QTY]0` fields, I get ‘Item name, amount and quantity are required if item category is provided.’ error (10003).

Comment: That is the code generating your API request.  I want to see the actual raw API request itself, as generated by this code.  Just like the sample set I provided earlier.

Comment: You said you can't reproduce the issue, but in what environment? My request fields are correct, I tried a hundred combinations so far, really. Did you run node.js with an Express router? Because I'm sure the problem there, otherwise why would a simple server restart solve the problem? So I'm rather asking for help with node.js or Express than PayPal, that's why I posted my code.

Comment: Furthermore, I tried to get a new token directly from PayPal with the same request fields rather than via my API while my server was stuck with an ‘invalid token’ or whatever error after the first flow, and I couldn't reproduce the issue too. But then I called my API again to get a token (`getCheckoutToken()` function) and the issue still was there. I restarted a server and the issue was gone. After that, I think it's pretty obvious that it has nothing to do with PayPal. =)

Comment: I left my server for 3 hours to let another ‘invalid token’ expire. Now I see ‘This Express Checkout session has expired.  Token value is no longer valid’ (10411) on SetExpressCheckout. I don't understand why PayPal doesn't want to revoke the token after CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

Comment: I've asked you numerous times for the info I need to help.  If you want to provide that info I'll be happy to look into this further with you. Without that info I cannot help you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm absolutely sure that the second SEC request is the same as the first one, it is clear from my code and the log (which is correct). Neither sessions/cookies are enabled, there is no any state sharing between router functions. Also, as I said before, if I remove line item fields (L_PAYMENTREQUEST_[...]) from CRPP, I start to get ‘Invalid token’ error (10410) on the second SEC. Seems the only way now is to contact PayPal MTS, I've run out of ideas.

Comment: @AndrewAngell can you please show me HTTP headers of the replicated on your test server request? And I can't complete subscription on your server, I get 404 on DoExpressCheckoutPayment.php after authorization, but my problem occurs only after CRPP request.

P.S. I contacted PayPal MTS, they helped to solve the error with totals, but can't help with invalid tokens (at least they are no longer respond). As always, here is my actual requests https://gist.github.com/nDmitry/10f8e967869d477bc8aa

Comment: In that particular sample I was only testing multiple SEC requests, however, I work with recurring payments heavily on my USBSwiper site.  You can [buy this item on my test server with a sandbox account](http://sandbox.usbswiper.com/usbswiper-point-of-sale-software-paypal.html) if you want to, and then go right back through the process again to see that a follow-up SEC request after completing CRPP works just fine.

Comment: I really feel like you've gotta have something going on with your sessions or something getting included in your request to PayPal that for some reason your log isn't capturing.  There's no reason PayPal would return an invalid token unless it was receiving a token in your SEC request.  I don't see one in your sample, though, which tells me that sample must not be accurate somehow..??

Comment: By the way, I'm curious what resolved the cart totals issue since I wasn't seeing those values in your request..??

Comment: I changed PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT from 0.00 to 5.00 to solve the cart totals issue. How I was told by PayPal MTS, I ‘made an order for 0 dollars, but try to capture 5 USD’. As for my requests, I really don't understand where any sessions can hide, I even tried to disable HTTP cache by setting Cache-Control, Pragma and Expires headers, say nothing of cookies. I think maybe PHP sends some HTTP headers node.js doesn't, that's why I asked you to show headers (and because our requests bodies is 100% the same).

Comment: I'm actually not sending any specific headers.